# The ADB at \platform-tools\adb.exe" is too old; please install version 1.0.39 or later. Error launching application on sdk gphone x86

Tags: android, adb

Appearance & Behaviour>System settings>Updates are up to date don't know what the error is ?

tried running in android studio

Comment: Search your system for `adb.exe`, may be you have multiple versions installed, one very old and one newer version? If that is the case delete the old one (or update it).